# How to figure out why all subdomains are pointing to the one folder in Ubuntu

Tags: virtualhost

I have a Laravel PHP & AngularJS web application at IP XXX.XX.XXX.XXX and when I load **either** the IP or **any** subdomain it loads the `var/www/html/example/application` folder. e.g. random.example.com will point to that folder or https://XXX.XX.XXX.XXX will point to that folder.

When I point a different domain to the server that is not `example.com` this does not happen.

However my problem is, I do not understand why. I would have thought the expected behaviour would be that only subdomain.example.com would point to it. Is there anywhere else on the server I should be looking out for that might be causing this?

Below is the `example.conf` file I use in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName subdomain.example.com
        Alias /api /var/www/html/example/public
        <Directory /var/www/html/example/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                RewriteEngine On
        </Directory>

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/application
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/STAR_example_com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example.com.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/STAR_example_com.ca-bundle     
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName subdomain.example.com
        Alias /api /var/www/html/example/public
        <Directory /var/www/html/example/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                RewriteEngine On
        </Directory>

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/application
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
            # SSLEngine on
            # SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/STAR_example_com.crt
            # SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example.com.key
            # SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/STAR_example_com.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the file 000-default.conf file at /etc/apache2/sites-available

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
#Redirect 403 /
#ErrorDocument 403 "Not allowed"

#Redirect 403 / 
#ErrorDocument 403 "Not allowed"


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.oldexample\.ie$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1.example.com$1 [R=302,L]

<Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

And default-ssl.conf in the same directory

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

    #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```